# Counting possible meal question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

Sara has 3 varieties of pasta, 4 different sauces, 5 kind of fruits, milk, juice and water. A meal is made from a variety of pasta and sauce, one fruit and a beverage, how many different meal can she prepare if she never drink juice?

I first begin with 3.4 for pasta and sauce but I don't know if I should add or multiply 5 kind of fruits and the 2 left kind of beverage.
Also there's 3 varieties of pasta but I don't think the question meant that different sauces can be mixed.

My answer is 3.4.5.2 = 120 but I'm not sure this is the right way of thinking or if there's a trick in the question.

Comment: For every pasta-sauce combination, she has $5$ choices of fruits.

Comment: Yes that is correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are correct, you multiply the options for each meal component and take a factor of 2 for the beverages to exclude juice and only keep milk and water.

So $4\times 3 \times 5 \times 2 = 5!= 120$ different meals are possible if each consists of exactly one pasta, one sauce, 1 fruit and one of 2 beverages.